# How do I align navbar items to right in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Now I know that similar questions have been dealt with here, but none of those solves my problem. So please understand. I've tried `ml-auto` next to `navbar-nav` class, but somehow the items are align to the left. Please see my code below:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand nav-bar fixed-top">
        <div class='navbar-brand nav-link' onclick="location.href='/'">
            <img class="ci" src="{% static 'museum/images/ci.png' %}" alt='ci'>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-text">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class='navbar-item'>Home</li>
                <li class='navbar-item my-auto'>Menu</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I haven't touched anything in the CSS, but the items are aligned to the left. What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you try with `ms-auto` and `me-auto`

Comment: I'm using bootstrap4. So far as I know, `ms-auto` works on Bootstrap5, am I right?

Comment: yes. It's with boostrap 5

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Bootstrap 4 :(

Comment: It's not working because you're not using the [correct Navbar structure](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#supported-content). `navbar-text` div does nothing.

Comment: **CSS:**  .navbar-item { margin-left: auto;}  This will align each page-link on the navbar to the right. If you have some social media links that you want on the navbar **but aligned to the left side** just make each a .smedia-item class and add {.smedia-item: margin-right: auto; }  For an elaboration on all this look at Kevin Powell's video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Azfj1efPAH0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to "collapse" div and add collapse div justify-content:flex-end;

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand nav-bar fixed-top">
    <div class='navbar-brand nav-link' onclick="location.href='/'">
        <img class="ci" src="{% static 'museum/images/ci.png' %}" alt='ci'>
    </div>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="justify-content:flex-end;" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class='navbar-item'>Home</li>
            <li class='navbar-item my-auto'>Menu</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This totally works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I miss navbar-toggler button I edit answer.

Comment: Oh in fact, I'm not intending the items to toggle in mobile screen. I'm keeping the items the same as pc screens. So I don't think I'll need the `toggle` part :)

Comment: oh okey, try this your original code

.navbar-text{ display:flex; justify-content:center;}